# Pycharm Create Branch off Branch

Tags: pycharm

I know how to create a branch off a branch in git from command line.  I am trying to use Pycharm and wondering - if I do a checkout in Pycharm for branch a and then do a git create branch b - is branch b created off branch a or off master?

master
 |------branch a
          |---------branch b

Comment: Did you ever find an answer? I tried to create a branch from a branch. It seemed to, but, it turned out, any changes I made in the new branch appeared in the branch it came from.